# Is there a collective word for the different "alphabets" used by different languages?

Tags: collective-nouns, alphabet

As I believe "alphabet" refers specifically to the latin a-z, is there a term that collectively refers to all collections of writing characters. ie, if I had a list that contained the entries "Latin, Kanji, Cyrillic" etc, what would that list be called? A single word is preferable, as I need the term to describe such a list in software I'm writing.

Note the answer is **not** "language" - eg English, French, German etc are all languages, but all use the Latin alphabet. On the other hand, Japanese is a language that can be written using Kanji, Hiragana, Katakana and Latin 'systems'. It's a hypernym for these 'systems' I'm after, not the languages.

Comment: You need to do some research. You could start by looking up "Greek alphabet", "Cyrillic alphabet", "Hebrew alphabet" etc. /  Even for very different character sets, 'alphabet' is used: 'The third alphabet, kanji, was imported over the centuries from China.' [[Japaneseup.com](https://japaneseup.com/learn-japanese-kanji-basic/)]

Comment: Hmm, I was sure I'd been taught that the "alphabet" was just the latin one - looks like I was wrong! Happy to accept this as an answer.

Comment: Not happy to give such an answer.

Comment: Then is alphabet not the correct collective term for what I have described?

Comment: Giving an 'answer' to a question lacking reasonable research does not help the site's credibility.

Comment: Many of us try to help as well as to maintain standards.

Comment: Which I appreciate, but if you don't believe the question should be here then it should be flagged / downvoted so that it will be closed and not seen. If you do, and you have an answer for it, put an answer. I have flagged it myself for a moderator to determine the best course of action.

Comment: You're telling me to do something I'd already done.

Comment: You could call "Latin, Kanji, ..." a *set of alphabets*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The OP's question does not lack justification or explanation. He explicitly mentions his notion that "alphabet" inherently refers to the Latin A-Z; which is the basis for his question (the OP's notion means that the OP disagrees with the usage of "Hebrew alphabet", even if he sees it being used). If you argue that existing documentation or usage precludes the validity of a question, that means (by elimination) that the only valid questions on this site must focus on topics that are currently undocumented, which is demonstrably not the case.

Comment: @Flater Here, looking up 'alphabet' in a reasonable dictionary is something I consider mandatory on a site aimed at linguists. 'As I believe ...' is unscholarly when there is such an obvious course of action.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OED seemingly confirms (or at least hints at) the OP's notion, mentioning that "alphabet" is defined "especially [as] the set of letters from A to Z". As English.SE also focuses on _usage_, there can be a difference between correctness and _communicating clearly_. E.g. going by dictionary definitions alone, "parking ticket" would be correct when referring to a parking permission (cfr "concert ticket"), but its usage would create an ambiguity with the already existing term for a parking fine. The OP is focusing on the best word to use in order to avoid misinterpretation.

Comment: Then OP should add basic research. 'Hmm, I was sure I'd been taught that the "alphabet" was just the latin [sic]  one - looks like I was wrong!' sets a wrong tone.

Comment: 'alphabet' works informally for Roman/Arabic/Devanagari, but technically is only for a very select few of those, and distinguishes between character for for phoneme (alphabet) vs character for consonant (abjad) vs character for syllable (syllabary). Writing systems that are not any one of these are things like Chinese or Mayan ideographs.

Comment: Kanji is not the same thing as an alphabet. Japanese, like Chinese is an "ideographic" language - where all the major parts of speech have pictograms which refer to the entire word. Hiragana and Katakana are of the nature of an alphabet, and are used within Japanese respectively for the minor parts of speech and foreign words. But kanji forms the main part of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Alphabet is the correct word.

> As I believe "alphabet" refers specifically to the latin a-z

Your assumption is wrong.

The etymological origin of the word "alphabet" relates to the Greek alphabet, in which the first two characters are "alpha" and "beta".

However, "alphabet" is currently used for **any** comprehensive set of characters. Take note of definition 1.1, which shows you that it can be used more loosely and does not even need to refer to a *linguistic* character set.

> [**Alphabet**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alphabet)
>   *noun*
>
> 1. A set of letters or symbols in a fixed order used to represent the basic set of speech sounds of a language, especially the set of letters from A to Z.
>      *‘the first letter of the alphabet’*
>      *‘a phonetic alphabet’*
>
>    1.1. The basic elements in a system which combine to form complex entities.
>      *‘DNA's 4-letter alphabet’*

The OED does mention that it can be taken to refer to the A-Z alphabet, **but not exclusively**.

---

### Tangentially

You've somewhat answered your own question. From your question body:

> English, French, German etc are all languages, but all use **the Latin alphabet**.

If you assume that "alphabet" inherently refers to the Latin A-Z, then why didn't you say:

> English, French, German etc are all languages, but all use **the alphabet**.

The fact that you have to say "the Latin alphabet" contradicts your notion that "alphabet" always refers to the Latin A-Z. That would make "Latin alphabet" a pleonasm.
Needing to specify *which* alphabet means that **there is more than one alphabet**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65126/discussion-on-answer-by-flater-is-there-a-collective-word-for-the-different-alp).

Comment: "Alphabet" technically excludes syllabaries, logographics, abjads, and abugidas. Even if some people include abjads and abugidas under alphabets, "alphabet" can never be used to refer to logographic writing systems.

Comment: @curiousdannii: `"alphabet" can never be used to refer to logographic writing systems` While logograms are indeed not considered letters, as long as it's possible to list _all_ logograms of a writing system (I'm not sure if e.g. Japanese characters can be dynamically modified, which means it's nigh impossible to list every permutation), then the set of logograms can still be called an alphabet based on definition 1.1. Calling it an alphabet might be avoided due to ambiguity (confusion between definition 1 and 1.1), but it's still a correct usage (even if prone to misinterpretation)

Comment: @Flater I would say, based on the example, and based all the times I've ever heard "alphabet" used, that definition 1.1 is only talking about non-linguistic systems. If you have counter examples, please do present them.

Comment: @curiousdannii: _"1.1 is only talking about non-linguistic systems"_ That's because you immediately assume any linguistic "alphabet" to be referring to definition 1, which your first comment indirectly proves (because everything you exclude, you are implicitly excluding from definition 1, not definition 1.1). Definition 1.1 intends to **include** non-linguistic sets, but it doesn't explicitly **exclude** fringe-case linguistic sets that somehow don't fit definition 1.

Comment: Do you have examples of a native speaker of English calling Egyptian hieroglyphics, or Japanese Kanji an "alphabet"? If 1.1 is not about non-linguistic senses of the word then it is completely irrelevant to this question. I would contend that it is a poorly written entry in a condensed online dictionary, but that anyone with native speaker intuitions will know that you just can't use the word "alphabet" to talk about logographic writing systems.

Comment: @curiousdannii: You're putting the cart before the horse. An example is not necessarily correct. Even if I find an example, how can anyone judge whether it's being used correctly? By observing the definition of the word "alphabet", which you find in the dictionary. Note that it's also perfectly possible for _jargon_ to override the _general English_ definition. To a programmer, C# is a programming language, but to a musician it's a note. Similarly, "alphabet" may have a stricter definition in the field fo linguistics, but the dictionary does not necessarily include jargon-specific differences.

Comment: @curiousdannii: _"If 1.1 is not about non-linguistic senses of the word then it is completely irrelevant to this question."_ Quite the opposite, actually. Removing your double negatives: _"If 1.1 is [also] about linguistic senses of the word then it is completely irrelevant to this question."_ That makes it **relevant**, because that means that even if Japanese Kanji isn't an alphabet (1 - linguistic character set), a **comprehensive** list of Kanji logograms is still an alphabet (1.1 - the basic elements in a system).

Comment: @Flater No, that's actually exactly what definition 1.1 is: jargon for non-linguistic systems. Outside of that, in both normal speech and linguistics, "alphabet" is just not used for ideographic writing systems.

Comment: "That makes it relevant, because that means that even if Japanese Kanji isn't an alphabet (1 - linguistic character set), a comprehensive list of Kanji logograms is still an alphabet (1.1 - comprehensive set of the basic elements in a system)" Just give us some examples. It shouldn't be hard if you're right.

Comment: @curiousdannii: "Not used" is not the same as "not correct". It may simply be be avoided (= unused) due to the ambiguity it introduces.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Any example I give, you can immediately refute by saying "well it's not using the word correctly", which brings us back to a discussion about whether the dictionary definition of "alphabet" applies to the usage or not. That's just a circular argument. And again, if the word "alphabet" is avoided in linguistic cases where 1 does not apply but 1.1 does, **the absence of its usage does not have any influence on whether it's correct**.

Comment: @Flater "Not correct" means, in this context, "not a meaning an educated native speaker would intend." I think my case is straightforward enough. Other dictionaries, encyclopedias, even ODO defn 1 say that "alphabet" is not a synonym of "writing system." ODO defn 1.1's example is non-linguistic. My argument isn't based on the ODO because I don't rate it highly enough. The full OED, maybe, but you didn't quote it :)

Comment: There are examples of "alphabet" being used for kanji, such as [this website](https://japaneseup.com/learn-japanese-kanji-basic/). They do exist. But ODO defn 1.1 can't be used to support them, because as you have pointed out, it's only for systems where all the elements can be listed.

Comment: @curiousdannii: You keep missing the point that even if **Japanese Kanji** is not an alphabet (1 - linguistic character set), **the comprehensive list of Japanese Kanji logograms** can still be considered an alphabet (1.1 - the basic elements in a system). Please do not that these two sentences are comparing different things (Kanji vs a list of all Kanji logograms).

Comment: @Flater But scripts like Kanji can't be exhaustively listed like that.

Comment: @curiousdannii: "it's only for systems where all the elements can be listed" I agree with you there, but that's why I've always added "comprehensive" to my answer, and to my comments that replied to you. If a comprehensive list cannot be made, then my statements inherently do not apply.

Comment: I believe linguists do not consider syllabaries, abjads, or ideographic scripts to be “alphabets.” The word is used that way in non-technical speech, though.

Answer (score 11):

I tend to follow [Omniglot](https://omniglot.com) and call them ***writing systems***. This is because Omniglot - and I believe linguistics generally - uses different terms depending on certain characteristics of the writing system and how it represents sounds of the language. For example, English, French, Greek, Korean hangul, and Russian are written with *alphabets*; Hindi, Bengali, and Gujarati are written with *abugidas*; Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac, Farsi, and Urdu are written with *abjads*; Japanese kana, Cherokee, and Canadian Aboriginal writing are called *syllabaries*; and Japanese kanji, Korean hanja, and Chinese hànzì are *ideograms*.

To touch briefly on the differences:

- An ***alphabet*** represents consonants and vowels each separately as individual letters.
- An ***abjad*** represents consonants only as distinct letters; vowels are represented as diacritics. In some cases, the vowels may be omitted entirely, and are implied from context (Hebrew does this quite often).
- An ***abugida*** represents consonants as separate letters, but the glyph used also implies a “default” vowel, and deletion or change of vowel is represented with modifications of the glyph, in a fashion similar to diacritics, but not the same.
- A ***syllabary*** represents a syllable of the language - usually *but not invariably* in the form CV (consonant followed by vowel) - as a single glyph; there is no necessary relationship between glyphs that carry the same consonant, or the same vowel.
- ***Ideograms*** use a single - often complex - glyph to represent a word or concept. In some languages, the ideogram may actually be compound, with one portion signalling the pronunciation, and another portion signalling the meaning.

Comment: I won't go any deeper, but [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abjad) defines << **abjad** (also abujad, abadjad, abjud) NOUN

1A system of notation in which each of the 28 letters of the Arabic alphabet is assigned a numerical value. Now chiefly historical. // 
2Linguistics. Any of various writing systems having symbols for consonants only; a consonantal alphabet. >> So 'alphabet' works here too.

Comment: Yes, "alphabet" covers a multitude of sins, but there is a distinct difference between an alphabet like the Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, or Korean Hangul, where consonants and vowels are on a more-or-less equal footing, and an alphabet/abjad like Hebrew, Syriac, or Arabic, where the vowels are represented by diacritics only. Using ODO's description, you could equally assert that 'alphabet' can be used for abugidas and syllabaries, as well. Oxford is a descriptive dictionary of _common_ usage, rather than _technical_ usage; it's not a source for linguistic terminology.

Comment: Hindi is a ***syllabilary***, not an alphabet. And I have never heard anybody call it the *"Hebrew abugida"*, only *"Hebrew alphabet"*.

Comment: @PeterShor - Nor am I asserting that Hindi is an alphabet; I am asserting that if you take EdwinAshworth's comment and ODO reference at face value, an abugida or syllabary could be called an 'alphabet' as easily as an abjad is. Hindi is _not_ a syllabary; it is an _abugida_; Hebrew is an _abjad_. You are correct that Cherokee is a _syllabary_, and I said so in my answer.

Comment: @PeterShor: If Hindi is a comprehensive set of symbols, then it is inherently an alphabet. "Alphabet" is also defined as ["the basic elements in a system which combine to form complex entities."](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alphabet), with the example of _"DNA's 4-letter alphabet"_ given, which completely forgoes the _linguistic_ context in favor of a generalized "list of symbols".

Comment: @Flater - ... which admittedly argues in favor of the accepted answer versus my technically more correct answer - but on that basis, one could argue that _alphabet_ is therefore _too_ general a term - because "the basic elements in a system which combine to form complex entities" could just as easily describe using Chinese ideograms to form sentences, making the complete set of Chinese ideograms into an 'alphabet', albeit one of enormous size and complexity.

Comment: I should note for the record that ODO does not have an entry at all for _abugida_.

Comment: An *abjad* is a type of *alphabet*, and an *abugida* is a type of *syllabary*. Saying that Hebrew is an abjad and not an alphabet, or that Hindi is an abugida and not a syllabary, is like saying that an elephant is a mammal and not an animal.

Comment: @PeterShor - I don't agree, and neither does Omniglot - and I suspect that linguistics professionals in general don't, either; Simon has shown that he does his homework. There is no question that there are similarities between abjads and alphabets, and between abugidas and syllabaries - but the level of similarity between abjads and abugidas is far closer than that between alphabets and syllabaries - the four terms represent four points on a continuum. Abjads are not alphabets, and abugidas are not syllabaries, any more than abugidas are abjads. The four terms exist for a reason.

Answer (score 7):

The [Unicode standard](https://www.unicode.org/), and [ISO 15924: Codes for the representation of names of scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924) use the term ***script***.

So, there is the *Latin script*, the *Han script* (which contains the Chinese *hànzì* / Japanese *kanji* / Korean *hanza*), the *Cyrillic script*, ...

In Unicode parlance, a *script* is a "*set of letters that are used together in writing languages*" <sup>[Unicode §2.2]</sup>, while a *writing system*<sup>*</sup> is "*the way a particular language is written*" <sup>[Unicode §6.1]</sup>, which can involve several scripts, e.g. "*the modern Japanese writing system uses four scripts: Han ideographs, Hiragana, Katakana and Latin (Romaji)*" <sup>[Unicode §6.1 again]</sup>.

The interested reader may also refer to [Unicode Standard Annex #24: Unicode Script Property](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr24/).

---

<sup>*</sup> In Unicode, *writing system* can also refer to "*a way that families of scripts may be classified by how they represent the sounds or words of human language*"<sup>[Unicode §6.1]</sup>, namely *alphabets*, *abjads*, *syllabaries*, *logosyllabaries*.

Comment: This is certainly a meaning of [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script); however the word is also used for any one of several ways of writing a given alphabet, e.g. cursive, antiqua, blackletter, ronde etc are scripts for the Latin alphabet. So there is possibly ambiguity. Some sources seem to differentiate between *script* meaning letter forms and *writing system* as including the rules for relating letter forms to sound (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_system)), so there is also that to consider.

Answer (score 2):

You may use **character(s)** or **character set**.

As you mention about alphabet, I assume your question is about classification of "writing system" according to relation between "sound unit" and "graphic representation".

Languages may use writing systems by implementing different set of **characters**. Usual process is to connect "sound unit" to a "graph". they may use alphabet at the phoneme level or syllabemes at syllable level or logograph at the word level.  These are different types of **characters** that are used to connect sound unit to graphs

Please check these:  [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logogram) for logograph ,  for [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet), for [Grapheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) and a page from [Western Washington University](http://pandora.cii.wwu.edu/vajda/ling201/test4materials/WritingHANDOUT.htm)

OED:
**Character:**

> **3 a. A member of a set of symbols used in writing or printing to represent linguistic elements, as individual speech sounds, syllables, or words; any of the simple elements of a written language, as a letter of an alphabet, or an ideogram.**
>
> 1490   W. Caxton tr. Boke yf Eneydos vi. sig. Bviij   *The Fenyces were the fyrst Inuentours of carecteris [Fr. carrecteres] dyfferencyng that one fro that other, of whiche were fourmed lettres for to write.*
>
> 1837   Penny Cycl. VII. vii. 32   *The Chinese characters or written words are symbols of ideas.*
>
> 1851   D. Wilson Archæol. & Prehistoric Ann. Scotl. iv. iv. 535   The Runic characters mingling with the initials and pilgrims' marks of the Holy Isle.
>
> 1910   Catholic Encycl. IX. 685/1   Many of the priests..use Arabic instead, but Arabic written in Syriac characters.
>
> 1952   ABA Jrnl. Oct. 837/2   The page..is neatly written in characters so small that a reader with average eyesight needs the aid of a magnifying glass in deciphering it.
>
> 2009   B. Mayhew & J. Bindloss Trekking in Nepal Himalaya 412/2   Each of these sounds is a different letter or character in the Devanagari script used to write Nepali.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? No offense intended.

Comment: @Flater because it answers the question *"if I had a list that contained the entries "Latin, Kanji, Cyrillic" etc, what would that list be called?"* It would be called / headed "characters"

Answer (score 0):

Another term that covers alphabets, syllabaries, ideographic scripts and so on, is “writing system.”  Some sources (including Wikipedia) consider the collection of glyphs the “script” and each method of using a script to write a language a “writing system.” By this definition, the use of simplified Chinese, traditional Chinese, Pinyin, Wade-Giles and Bopomofo to write Mandarin are all different “writing systems,” and the use of Latin script to write German and Vietnamese are different writing systems too.

Answer (score 0):

> As I believe 'alphabet' refers specifically to the Latin a - z.

Your belief is wrong.

The alphabet, just by its name, is related to ancient semitic origins, the traces of which remains in Hebrew, for example, the first two letters of the Hebrew alphabet is Aleph & Beth, and so, alphabet. But it's origin goes even further back to Proto-Canaanite, also known as the Phoenician alphabet and influenced the alphabets of Arabic, Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew & Latin.

Further, the term - alphabet - in it's modern meaning means simply all the basic written symbols - known as letters or graphemes - used in a language that uses these symbols to represent a phoneme.

Thus the collective name for a collection of alphabets is 'alphabets' - like I have already used in this sentence.

> if I had a list containing 'Latin, Kanji, Cyrillic', what would that list be called?

Whilst both Latin and Cyrillic use alphabets, Kanji is logographic; hence to refer to the list above, one would say, alphabets and logographies.

All writing systems come under alphabets, syllabaries, logographies and ideograms. Some used mixed systems like the Japanese where they have both a syllabary and a logography; in Chinese, they use a fusion of a syllabary and a logography and ancient Egyptian heiroglyphic is ideogrammatic. There is no one word to cover them all.

If you wish to use a term that covers all of them, its best to use an invented term for this. For example, alis, which is an acronym of alphabet, logogram, ideogram and syllabary. The other option is to choose one of these to represent all of them. Semantically speaking the best one to choose is ideograms since all 'letters' originated from such.

Answer (score -2):

Most answers are correct as far as they go.
Alphabets are individual characters or character sets that in themselves have no meaning.
In the case of Kanji the symbols are ideograms and each one holds meaning within itself, or put another way, is a word or concept.
Even though Kanji can be put together to form other words or concepts this is a totally different process and concept than the letters of an alphabet.
Katakana and Hiragana are alphabets as each symbol represents a sound and not an idea.

Comment: This does not answer the question, however. Please wait until you have sufficient reputation to leave comments.